# How to do a lookup from a secondary collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am building a simple chat client in Meteor. A chat message is stored in the Chats collection which has a message containing the id of the user from which it is and the id to which user it is, as well as the message, like so:

```
   {
     "_id" : "3Wo3EHYG8oPCS4TCc",
     "message" :
      {
         "from" : "oSiKCdvCHGrfnfQoT",
         "to" : "ESXbJXeWmNanz7zKq",
         "text" : "Hello"
       }
    }
```

Users are store in the collection Users, which has the id as well as the username:

```
    meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find()
    { "_id" : "oSiKCdvCHGrfnfQoT", "username" : "user1" }
    { "_id" : "ESXbJXeWmNanz7zKq", "username" : "user2" }
```

I have an HTML-page that displays messages like this

```
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{#each messages}}
    From {{message.from}} to {{message.to}}: {{message.text}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

using the following template helper:

```
Chats = new Mongo.Collection("chats");
Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
import './main.html';

Template.hello.helpers({
  messages:function(){
    return Chats.find();
  }
})
```

This creates the following output:

```
   Test
   From oSiKCdvCHGrfnfQoT to ESXbJXeWmNanz7zKq: Hello
```

However, in the HTML-page, I want to lookup the usernames of the users, instead of displaying their raw ids. I know that I could store the usernames in the Chats collection, but I would rather keep it clean. Of course, I could also do the lookup in the template helper function, and create a new datastructure, which mimics messages, but replaces the IDs with usernames. However, this is a rather clumsy solution, and I would rather do the lookup on the HTML-side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that you can use all over your templates:

```
Template.registerHelper('username',function(userId){
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
  return user && user.username;
});
```

Then in any template you can simply do `{{username message.from}}` (for example) and the username will automatically be inserted.